# While Upgrading JDK version from 8 to 11 for the maven project, test is getting failed

Tags: java, maven-3, java-11, maven-surefire-plugin

Error:

[image: error image]

[image: second error]

I am trying to upgrade jdk from 1.8 to 11. But it is giving me an error.

Test cases are getting failed.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>surefire</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <argLine>
            --add-opens java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
            -Xmx1024m</argLine>
                        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Manager:

```
<pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
      <!-- not required this plugin -->
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.22.2</version>
         <configuration>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            <argLine>
               --add-opens java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
            </argLine>
            <excludes>
               <exclude>**/*RegressionTest.java</exclude>
            </excludes>

            <forkCount>1</forkCount>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
         <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.3.0.603</version>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I have tried with changing the surefire version. So issue get changed. But I am not able to get the solution for the above error.

Comment: I can't read that error screenshot.  This is a big, broad problem.  You've waited too long to upgrade.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: First Upgrade your testng version also upgrade surefire-plugin version to most recent version (3.0.0-M7). Why are those `--add-opens` needed? Also the sonar-maven-plugin is too old (https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin). Which Maven version do you use? Are all plugins uptodate? Check here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/